# Python / mongoDB Issue

Tags: python, mongodb-query

I am learning how to use Python against mongoDB and am having difficulty understanding why I am unable to return a `"$avg"` aggregate value.  I have a very small collection (9 records total) against which I appear to successfully use the `"$match"` aggregate function first to limit the documents (appear to pass along 3 documents further downstream in the pipeline).  But for some reason the `"$avg"` value is not being calculated.

Here is the code I am using:

```
db.scores.aggregate( [
    { "$match" : { "test" : "quiz1" } },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : { "first" : "$first", "last" : "$last", "score" : "$score" }, "avgScore" : { "$avg" : "$score" } } }
    ])
```

And here is the output I receive:

```
{u'ok': 1.0, u'result': [{u'_id': {u'score': u'88', u'last': u'Black', u'first': u'Tom'}, u'avgScore': 0.0},
                         {u'_id': {u'score': u'87', u'last': u'Jones', u'first': u'Mary'}, u'avgScore': 0.0},
                         {u'_id': {u'score': u'89', u'last': u'Smith', u'first': u'Jay'}, u'avgScore': 0.0}]}
```

I don't understand why an `"$avg"` score is not returned for the 3 records that are making it to the "$group" statement in the pipeline.

Any thoughts/comments/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `$avg` operator works on `numeric` values and ignores non numeric values.

> Returns the average value of the numeric values that result from
>   applying a specified expression to each document in a group of
>   documents that share the same group by key. $avg ignores non-numeric
>   values.

Your results `u'score': u'88'` indicate that the `score` field is a of type `String`. You need to store them as `Numbers`.